# what is the Best way to "Set" the IFormFile filename?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iformfile

I'm trying to find a way to change the filename of an IFormFile property.

The issue is this:

When a user uploads a file on our form, this method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(LendOutEquipmentViewModel model)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid && model.Picture!=null) //model.Title != null && model.Description != null &&
            {
                long size = model.Picture.Sum(f => f.Length);

                foreach (var picture in model.Picture)
                {
                    if (picture.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var uniqueFileName = GetUniqueFileName(picture.FileName);
                        var uploadFolderPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Upload");
                        var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolderPath,uniqueFileName);

                        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
                        {
                            await picture.CopyToAsync(stream);
                        }
                    }
                }
                DbContext.Equipments.Add(model);
                DbContext.SaveChanges();
                return Redirect("/BorrowEquipment");

            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

will add some chars to the end of the filename, to ensure it's unique, but the model won't get updated, so when it's saving the filename to the database it will use the filename from the model.

But isn't there a way to update the filename in the model?
as I can see the IFormFile.filename doesn't have a setter I can't just set it, I have tried creating a new `iFormFile` object and replacing the one in the model, but that didn't work either.

So my question is, what would be the best way to update the model so the changes made to the filename are properly saved?

Comment: Why do you need to modify that particular `IFormFile` in the first place? You can always add new field for that generated file name as a part of `LendOutEquipmentViewModel`... and use it from there in your view...

Comment: Have you tried calling `picture.FileName = uniqueFileName;` after `CopyToAsync()`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yup, that's not possible, because of the property only got a get;

Comment: @Dusan Thank You! My partner and I were both "Why didn't we think of that".